# Text watcher auto complete only works for first character typed and then stops

Tags: android, kotlin, textwatcher, android-textwatcher

So I'm using a text watcher to show the user suggestions for tags.
Currently I am using a dummy list of tags. When the user starts typing, the code should create a another list of tags that is just the objects of the first list filtered based on whether they contain the character sequence the user is currently typing.

It works great for the first character, but as the user keeps typing the list doesn't change anymore.

This is my code:

```
 val tags = listOf(
        "John Smith",
        "Kate Eckhart",
        "Emily Sun",
        "Frodo Baggins",
        "Yanay Zabary",
        "Sze Lok Ho",
        "Jesse Albright",
        "Shayna something",
        "Makena Lawrence"
    )

        questionTagsInput.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

            val userInput = s.toString()

            if (userInput == "") {
                tagSuggestionRecycler.visibility = View.GONE
                tagsFiltredAdapter.clear()


            } else {
                val relevantTags: List<String> = tags.filter { it.contains(userInput) }

                for (t in relevantTags) {
                    tagSuggestionRecycler.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    tagsFiltredAdapter.add(SingleTagSuggestion(t))
                }

            }

        }


        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        }

    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need to **clear** the `tagsFiltredAdapter` in each call of `onTextChanged`.
Currently, when typing the first character, your filtered list contains the right results, and when typing more characters, the list's size should decrease to match the new characters. Instead, you just adding items to the list.